# Posicionar dos componentes de react en la misma línea

Tags: css, html5, reactjs

Tengo dos componentes de react en un div uno son tres dados y otro un botón para lanzarlos, ambos están dentro de un div, el problema es que ambos aparecen en pantalla uno debajo del otro y los necesito en la misma línea, como consigo eso?

```
     <div id="dices">
      <ReactDice
        numDice={this.state.armies}
        rollDone={this.rollDoneCallback}
        outline
        faceColor="#0001ff"
        dotColor="#000100"
        disableIndividual
        ref={dice => (this.reactDice = dice)}
        id="dice"
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={this.rollAll}
        id="buttonDice"
      >
        Tirar los dados
      </Button>
    </div>
```

El css de ese div es:

```css
#dices{
  background-color: blue;
  position:fixed;
  left: 50%;
  right: 23%;
  bottom:0px; 
  height: 15%; 
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dale un `width: 100%` y cambia `display: block` por `display:flex` de esa manera tendrás todos los items del div alineados en la misma fila, ya que, corríjanme si me equivoco, flex por defecto es el comportamiento que tiene. Aunque sino fuera así puedes cambiarlo usando la propiedad `flex-direction: column`